# Neo4j: How to uninstall Neo4j from mac?

Tags: neo4j

I cannot find any instructions to uninstall Neo4j from the mac. I am seeing instructions to remove it from Ubuntu, windows but not anything for osx/mac.

Answer (score 5):

To uninstall the Neo4j Desktop (with default configuration) from a Mac:

- Delete `Neo4j Desktop.app` from the `Applications` folder.
- Delete the `~/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop` folder.

Comment: Folder `~/.neo4j` might be existing, so delete that one also :).